# How to run a reminder every Friday only once in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Friends,

I am trying to place a reminder in my wp8 app that should execute every Friday before 8:00 AM only once. I am using `ScheduledAgent` but don't know much about it.

Below I am using very basic to check if it's Friday, but don't how to launch the notification.

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
   string toastMessage = "MyApp reminder";
   ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
   toast.Title = "Friday Activity";
   toast.Content = toastMessage;
   toast.Show();

   //execute every day only once
   if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
   {
       //How to Launch the reminder or notification only once
   }

   #if DEBUG_AGENT
     ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
   #endif

  NotifyComplete();
}
```

Starting the periodic from Foreground using below

```
void StartPeriodicAgent()
{
   periodicTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(periodicTaskName) as PeriodicTask;
   if (periodicTask != null)
       RemoveAgent(periodicTaskName);

    periodicTask = new PeriodicTask(periodicTaskName);

    periodicTask.Description = "MyApp reminder.";
    try
    {
         ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
         PeriodicStackPanel.DataContext = periodicTask;

         #if(DEBUG_AGENT)
              ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
         #endif
     }
     ....
  }
```

How to call the notification every Friday only once? This executes every 1 minute, but I don't how to make it only in Fridays.

Thanks!

Comment: In what way is it "every Friday" if it's "only once"? Isn't that just "next Friday"? It may be that you're thinking of something that makes sense, but I don't understand what you mean at the moment. Is it "only once per Friday, but every Friday"? That would make some sense, I think...

Comment: Thanks, It's notify the user only once every Friday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...that should execute every Friday before 8:00 AM only once...

So I assume you want to launch the notification **every friday, but only once on that day**.

You need to check not only for the day of week, but also store a date and then check this as well:

```
  //execute every day only once
   if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday && storedDate <> DateTime.Today)
   {
       //How to Launch the reminder or notification only once
   }
```

---

> ...but don't know how to launch the notification.

I don't know either sorry. Maybe others know an answer here.

Comment: Thanks, Do I need to remove the `#if(DEBUG_AGENT)` section and place the `toast` inside `if` condition?

Comment: @ARH yes, you could do that. There are multiple ways of how to achieve this. You could also check at the beginning of OnInvoke and then simply 'return' if dayOfWeek is not friday or storedDate is today.